# ¿Qué parámetro recibe un valor retornado, de una función recursiva de 2 o más parámetros?

Tags: c++, funciones, recursión

Si no entienden mi pregunta, aquí un ejemplo de una función recursiva:

```
int ejemplo(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 1) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return a + ejemplo(a, b - 1);
    }
}
```

No entiendo qué parámetro de esta función recibe el valor retornado `2`.

Esta es la parte donde un parámetro recibe el valor retornado `2`:

```
if (b == 1) {
    return 2;
}
```

Ya he depurado esta función pero no entiendo como funciona exactamente... Que alguien me explique esa función por favor.

¡Gracias de antemano!

PD: He investigado por otras partes y sigo con la misma duda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la recursion suele ser algo dificil de entender sin embargo una vez comprendido se puede usar de manera sorprendente.

Para entender a la recursion es bueno que lo imagines como un apilado de llamadas una sobre otra, estas llamadas se van apilando (esperando la respuesta a la nueva llamada realizada) hasta que en algun momento cumple la condicion y deje de apilar (deja de llamar), ahora empieza a responder es decir desapilar.

Para el ejemplo que propusiste intentare explicarlo con el siguiete grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva, tambien me costo ami entender la recursion.

Comment: Ok, te entiendo, tengo dos preguntas: ¿Porqué b es el que recibe el valor y no a? y ¿Con qué parámetro se suma a, con el a o el b?

Comment: Cuando llamas a una función, se pasan parámetros, en y según el orden la función sabe si es "a" o "b" , que son representadas como variables, en este caso ambos al llamar a la función se le envían dos valores, respondiendo a la segunda pregunta "a" se suma con el resultado de la llamada a la función "ejemplo" recuerda que la función "ejemplo" recibe dos parámetros y devuelve un resultado.

Comment: Vale, vale, Ok. ¿Me recomiendas algún material para poder dominar mejor la recursividad?

Comment: si quieres dominar la recursividad intenta convertir las funciones secuenciales o cíclicas en funciones recursivas, toma en cuenta que una función re cursiva básicamente consta de dos partes:
1. el caso base o condición de parada
2. el paso recursivo es decir donde se llama a si mismo con una variación del o los parámetros de manera que conduzca a acercarse al caso o condicion de parada

Comment: Ok, ok, ya por fin, alguien que me explicó bien la recursividad! Iba a dejar la programación por ese tema, pero ya por fin lo entiendo, gracias!

Answer (score 9):

> No entiendo qué parámetro de esta función recibe el valor retornado `2`.

Ninguno. El valor de retorno no alimenta ningún parámetro, el valor de retorno se suma al valor de retorno de otra llamada:

```
int ejemplo(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 1) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return a + ejemplo(a, b - 1);
//             ^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//             |                   \__________ lo que devuelva la llamada a la función.
//             \___ Parámetro 'a' se suma a...
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, el parámetro `b` sólo alimenta otros parámetros `b` de otras llamadas a `ejemplo`, suponiendo que llamamos `ejemplo(1, 3)` el árbol de llamadas sería:

```
ejemplo(1, 3)
        |\  \
        | \  \_(3 - 1)_
        |  \_______    \
        |          \   |
        1 + ejemplo(1, 2)
                    |\  \
                    | \  \_(2 - 1)_
                    |  \_______    \
                    |          \   |
                    1 + ejemplo(1, 1)
                                |   \
                                |    \
                                x     \___ 2
```

Como ves, el retorno nunca forma parte de los parámetros.

Answer (score 3):

Los parámetros de una función recursiva no reciben los valores retornados en la recursión. Ciertamente puedes asignar el resultado de una recursión al parámetro de la misma, pero no es tu caso.

Tu función devuelve el resultado de la recursión a quien lo pidió, no lo almacena en ningún parámetro de la propia función recursiva.

Lo que ocurre es que:

- Si `b` es 1, se devuelve 2 a la función desde donde se invocó a esta función, que puede ser la propia función (nivel superior de la recursión).
- En caso contrario, la función se queda a la espera de que se complete la llamada recursiva, y el resultado devuelto por la llamada recursiva se suma con el parámetro `a` y se devuelve al invocador, que de nuevo puede ser otra función o un nivel superior de la recursión.

Un ejemplo práctico:

```
int main(void)
{
    int resultadoFinal = ejemplo(1, 2);
    printf("%d", resultadoFinal);  // Impresión Estilo C (cstdio)
    cout << resultadoFinal;        // Impresión de C++ (iostream)
    return 0;
}
```

Su ejecución sería:

- La función `main` declara una variable entera que almacenará el resultado de la llamada `ejemplo(1, 2)`, y se queda a la espera de que se complete dicha llamada.
- Se asignan los argumentos `1` y `2` a los parámetros `a` y `b`, y se entra a ejecutar la función `ejemplo`.
- Como el parámetro `b` es distinto de 1, se ejecuta el bloque `else`, es decir, se va a devolver el contenido del parámetro `a` más el resultado de llamar otra vez a `ejemplo`, pero esta vez decrementando `b`, con lo que se producirá una llamada `ejemplo(1, 1)`, quedando `ejemplo(1, 2)` a la espera de que esa llamada se complete.
- El valor de `b` en `ejemplo(1, 2)` no cambia, porque la resta no se va a almacenar en su parámetro `b`, sino en el parámetro `b` de la llamada `ejemplo(1, 1)`. Aquí está la clave: cada llamada tiene sus propios parámetros `a` y `b`.
- Ahora bien, dentro de `ejemplo(1, 1)`, como su parámetro `b` vale 1, se devuelve 2 al invocador, que era `ejemplo(1, 2)`, que estaba a la espera.
- La llamada `ejemplo(1, 2)` recibe el valor 2 de `ejemplo(1, 1)` y lo suma con el valor de su `a`, que era 1, y devuelve el resultado, que es 3, a su invocador, que era `main`.
- La función `main` sale de su espera y recibe de `ejemplo(1, 2)` el valor 3, que asigna a la variable `resultadoFinal`, que se imprimirá por pantalla justo a continuación.

La clave aquí está en que **cada llamada a una función tiene sus propios parámetros y variables locales**. El **invocador se queda a la espera** de que la función le devuelva algún valor (si no es una función con tipo de retorno `void`). Y al hacer una llamada cualquiera, los valores de **los argumentos se copian en los parámetros** de la función.

Comment: >Tu función devuelve el resultado de la recursión a quien lo pidió, no lo almacena en ningún parámetro de la propia función recursiva.                                                     
                                                                                                               
Tengo dos pregunta:¿quién pidió el resultado? ¿quién recibirá el resultado?

Comment: En la respuesta lo explico: la llamada inicial la hace el `main`, por que el resultado de la llamada a `ejemplo(1, 2)` se devolverá desde esta función  al `main`. Dentro de la recursión, el resultado de `ejemplo(1, 1)` se devolverá a `ejemplo(1, 2)`, y de ahí, como he mencionado antes, se sumará y devolverá al `main`.

Comment: Ahora que lo veo de otra manera, ya lo logro entender... Creo que fui un poco tonto , en el principio tú mismo lo dijiste: tu función devuelve el resultado de la recursión a quien lo pidió, no lo almacena en ningún parámetro de la propia función recursiva, gracias, ya estoy dominando la recursividad.

Comment: Ninguna pregunta es tonta si tiene como objetivo aprender algo que no se sabe. A mí también me costó al principio. Solo ten en cuenta que para un computador no hay diferencia entre una llamada a una función normal o recursiva: se guarda el estado del hilo de ejecución, se preparan los argumentos de la llamada poniéndolos en pila, y se comienza a ejecutar la función invocada, para luego devolver el resultado al invocador. Lo único que cambia es que se detiene la ejecución de la función recursiva para volver a ejecutar su mismo código, desde el principio, pero con otros argumentos.

Comment: No me refería a mi pregunta era tonta sino el comentario, aunque casi no lo es, pero esta bien. Ya estoy entendiendo... Solo más práctica y ya podré dominar la recursividad!